# RF Switch Component Identification

Tags: rf, identification, components

I'm trying to identify the IC chip below, which I believe to be an RF Switch. Any help anyone can offer regarding who the manufacturer might be and/or what the part number might be would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Not enough info. Good ruck

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I went digging and got a bit more info (not sure it will help). The RF Switch is a SP3T topology...

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I've turned up a little more information still. The RF Switch has three control signals (VCTL1 on pin 1, VCTL2 on pin 11, and VCTL3 on pin 3

Comment: If the outputs are pins 1, 3 and 9 and input is pin 11, then Skyworks SKY13373-460LF is a match. RF switch for WLAN. Except Skyworks mark their parts better. This one here might be "made by Ali Baba". I searched for "QFN12 SP3T RF switch".

Comment: Even alibaba marks them better on photos https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32598943349.html

Comment: @Lundin yea I did my basic Digikey diligence and saw those Skyworks parts as well. I suspect I could make work with some glue logic, but they have two control signals as compared to the three this mystery part allegedly has.

Comment: ... so it wouldn't be a drop-in replacement (just completing my thought))